# Ocultar elementos según tamaño de dispositivo con react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando `react-bootstrap 4.3` y quiero ocultar elementos según tamaño del dispositivo, se me ocurre hacerlo con media query, pero prefiero hacerlo usando las clases de bootstrap.

He intentado de las siguientes maneras :

```
<Nav.Link className=" d-xs-none d-sm-none" >
   <Link to="/" className="navLink"> Home </Link>
</Nav.Link>


<Nav.Link sm={false}  className="" >
   <Link to="/" className="navLink"> Home </Link>
</Nav.Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase 'd-xs-none' no existe en esta versión de bootstrap por lo que para ese breakpoint no te servirá lo que has colocado en esa parte del código. Si puedes jugar con 'd-none' y 'd-block' para conseguir el resultado que buscas, cómo por ejemplo:

```
 <Nav.Link className="d-none d-md-block" >
     <Link to="/" className="navLink"> Home </Link>
 </Nav.Link>
```

Te dejo un enlace a la documentación dónde se explica con detalle el uso del 'display' con bootstrap y react por si te resulta de ayuda: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/utilities/display/